# Getting an objectId from AAD by email

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure Active Directory. I have a demand for following functionality: I need to get an objectId of the user who is not invited into my resource group/subscription. Just some Azure user providing an e-mail. Is there any kind of API to do this? I have tried to look into Graph API, but didn't notice a suitable method.

Technology stack is ReactJS. Currently, using ADAL, but it is suitable for authorization and I didn't find a functionality to get information about non-curent users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain user's details from Graph API using id or userPrincipalName (which is an email address).

From Microsoft [Graph API reference:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```